# How can I get spacing between buttons in a justified button group?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add spacing between buttons in a Bootstrap button group. I understand this is possible by using a button toolbar instead, however, I cannot work out how to make that justified (ie. fill a width of 100%). This is a feature I need and, as far as I can work out, is only possible with button groups.

The code below creates a bar of buttons that are attached to one another with no spacing. I would like them to appear inline as individual buttons, spaced equally, with widths proportionate to the length of the text.

```css
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" id="indicative">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled" id="indicative-present">present</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled" id="indicative-preterite">preterite</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled" id="indicative-imperfect">imperfect</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled" id="indicative-conditional">conditional</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled" id="indicative-future">future</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to flexbox!

- [Enable flex behaviors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors)
- [Flex fill](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#fill)

Also, to make things a little less cramped...

- [Spacing utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/)

And for the sake of this demo...

- [Background color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/colors/#background-color)
- [Borders](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/borders/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex bg-light border py-1" id="indicative">
  <button type="button" id="indicative-present"
    class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled flex-fill mx-1">present</button>
  <button type="button" id="indicative-preterite"
    class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled flex-fill mx-1">preterite</button>
  <button type="button" id="indicative-imperfect" 
    class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled flex-fill mx-1">imperfect</button>
  <button type="button" id="indicative-conditional" 
    class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled flex-fill mx-1">conditional</button>
  <button type="button" id="indicative-future" 
    class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled flex-fill mx-1">future</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `mx-1` to your bootstrap button class to add space between the buttons.

```css
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn-group" role="group" id="indicative">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled mx-1" id="indicative-present">present</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled mx-1" id="indicative-preterite">preterite</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled mx-1" id="indicative-imperfect">imperfect</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled mx-1" id="indicative-conditional">conditional</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary shadow-none disabled mx-1" id="indicative-future">future</button>
</div>
```